# Why am I able to access my Docker-Compose container via localhost in the host web browser but not in the container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two containers: one for Cypress and another for my web app. I have them both set up in a `docker-compose.yml` file like so:

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  pa-portal:
    image: web_app_image
    container_name: pa_portal
    volumes:
      - productDB:/web_app/db
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
  cypress:
    image: "cypress/included:4.4.0"
    depends_on:
      - pa-portal
    environment:
      - CYPRESS_baseUrl=http://pa-portal:8080
    working_dir: /cypress-testing

    volumes:
      - ./:/cypress-testing

volumes:
  productDB:
```

From the Cypress (testing framework) container I am able to access the web app using `http://pa-portal:8080` but from a browser on my host the only way I can access the web app that has been launched by the `pa_portal` container is using `localhost:8080`.

Why are there different urls depending on where I am accessing from?

Is there some fundamental knowledge i need to do some research on

Comment: If you were able to access the container in that way, why would you need those port mappings? Those DNS names are resolvable only within a docker environment.

Comment: @MatusDubrava I have edited the question - it's not that I want to, I am just wondering why

Comment: Answering that fundamental knowledge question - you need to know how DNS works in general (DNS servers and local config, ex `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/resolv.conf`). Then you need to understand how Docker service discovery works.

Comment: And the question about different urls - because those (your localhost and docker environment) are different networks with their own rules.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is working as designed.

The service name is just a redirect WITHIN the docker-infrastructure. It doesn't work like a hosts-entry for outside of this scope.

To get what you want look into Traefik .
You can set it up with a docker container, add labels to your docker compose and with that traeffik will route your localhost to the given domainname you want.

I googled a simple howto for that, but the traefik docs are fine too:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-traefik-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-docker-containers-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: I have edited the question - I am wondering more on the why not the how

Comment: Well, because it is what it is: Docker is a software on your computer, it doesnt change your HOSTS file, so basicly your Browser doesnt know your domain "pa_portal". That is not what docker do and is there by design. With traefik you have a software exactly for that :)

Comment: Traefik also doesn't edit hosts entries. It's just acting as a proxy